# how to optimize aspx page when it has several script files included inside it?

Tags: javascript

i have an aspx page which contains script references to many javascript and css files(about 10 or more). the problem is as you would expect is the slow loading time of the page. i tried to move some of the scripts to the end of the page but this did not make any difference. my question is how to deal with numerous script files in order to speed up page load time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use code obfuscators to minimize the size of your files.  I normally use Dojo's shrinksafe for javascript: 
http://o.dojotoolkit.org/docs/shrinksafe
Or the YUI Compressor: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

and code beautifier for css: http://www.codebeautifier.com/

but there are many others out there.  You just need to be sure to do a full regression test after you compress.

Answer (score 3):

What do you mean by 'loading' time?

1. Is it a download time from server to client? - merge files, compress them and set expiry headers. Compress html, or render less HTML ;-). Use Content Delivery Network.
2. Is it the rendering of the page? - review CSS rules to make sure you don't have suboptimal / unused ones, defer execution of javascript that is not needed instantly, consider using jQuery live events.

Check your CPU - you may have some javascript updating a lot of DOM or doing long loops.

Analyze your page using **[PageSpeed](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/)** or **[YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/)** for more information.

Comment: you mentioned : "consider using jQuery live events." but why?

Comment: If you use $.live to attach a handler to let's say click event than only one handler is attached, regardless of the number of elements. if you use $.click than a handler is attached to each DOM element separately.

Answer (score 1):

Try the same page as plain HTML (view/save source) to ensure is not .NET's whopping VIEWSTATE blob that is cause of your slow-down.

Answer (score 0):

as said by others; combine (into 1 js & 1 css-file) & compress ([minimize](http://jscompress.com/) and use [gzip output compression in IIS](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/perfworld/archive/2009/01/27/how-do-i-enable-gzip-compression-on-my-web-site-in-iis.aspx)).

if you can't combine all of your javascript into one file (as some of it might be external), you should [consider using labjs, a small library to load javascript](http://labjs.com/) in an efficient, unobtrusive and performant manner.